# How to configure FireFox to see WIndows certificate in cert store?

Tags: firefox

How to configure FireFox to see WIndows certificate in cert store?

In Edge/Chrome, when I go to a website, it promopts me a list of certificate to use from my certificate in cert store?

I have tried the following, but when I go to the same site, FF does not prompt me for any certificate and i can't go to that site with FF.

```
In Firefox, type 'about:config' in the address bar
If prompted, accept any warnings
Right-click to create a new boolean value, and enter 'security.enterprise_roots.enabled' as the Name
Set the value to 'true'
```

Can you please tell me how can i fix this issue wiht FF?

Comment: It does not prompt for your certificate because that setting only tells FF that it should trust the "Enterprise root certificates" from Windows Certificate Store but it won't do anything with your personal certificates. AFAIK you have to import your personal certificates into FF's own cert store to be able to authenticate on a website using your personal certificate.

Comment: But how can I import my personal certificates to FF own cert store? From this link, it shows there is NOT folder where the cert is stored. It is stored in a blog in reg key?

Comment: In latest Firefox open `about:preferences#privacy`, scroll down and there is a `View certificates` button. On `Certificate Manager` select `Your certificates` tab and there is an `Import...` button.